# Jquery.load() cannot work with Firefox, since the javascript dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I use jquery.laod() to load html snippet in index.html, and in the html use **script** element to load javascript, javascript packed by webpack, like this:

**Index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piece"></div>
    <script>
       $(function(){
         $("#piece").load("piece.html");
       });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="framework/xxxxx.js"></script><script 
    type="text/javascript" src="vendor/yyyyy.js">
    </script>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     angular.module('app.plugins', []);
  </script>
</html>
```

**piece.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/zzzzz.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app.plugins').requires.push('zzz');
</script>
```

The javascript yyyyy.js depends on zzzzz.js.
this solution could work with chrome but not work with Firefox, and raise exception: can not find the dependency.

So I guess it's caused by difference between the loading policy of Chrome and firefox, is that right?

Comment: You have not closed `#piece` div in html, your jquery code replace everything inside this div, just close this div before script to solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, it's my type error, has correct it, thanks

Comment: A general problem with this approach is that `piece.html` cannot load on its own because it won't have its dependencies and they cannot be loaded via script tags because that would cause conflicts when it is loaded as a part of a larger application (as is the case here). Look into a proper module loader such as RequireJS.

Comment: Agree with you, but it's weird the solution could work with Chrome